# Custom attribute

Tags: php

```
get: fn ($value) => ["user", "editor", "admin"][$value]
```

I have only seen that code from youtube but I don't understand what this line of code does. Does this work like a map in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an arrow function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

That code is equivalent to this:

```
get: function ($value) {
    $arr = ["user", "editor", "admin"];

    return $arr[$value];
}
```